# DataGrid: привязка данных

Tags: c#, wpf

`DataGrid` привязан к таблице в БД с помощью перетаскивания из окна "Источники данных". Как сделать чтобы изменения, внесенные в `DataGrid`, заносились в таблицу в БД, т.е. изменяли ее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы работаете с MS SQL сервером (про MySql и другие ничего сказать не могу, но помоему для большинства из них такое тоже есть), то можно использовать [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) + [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx). Причем если выборки не сложные (без JOIN'ов), то [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) сам сгененрирует инструкици добавления/удаления/обновления. Если же выборки не простые, то, на сколько я помню, эти инструкции придется прописывать самому. Если заинтересует, то могу привести небольшой пример.

Answer (score 0):

Надо вручную писать код,
например грид выглядит так: `ID -ФИО- Арес-дата_рождения` и т.д.
Хранить можно это дело классе, в котором сделать оператор `set`.
пользователь меняет адрес(или что-то др.)
и надо создать запрос на изменение update. (смотри `SQL`)
Привязываешь метод в `set {....}` и всё.
Ну или создаёшь кнопку - Сохранить, которая сохраняет значения строки, на которой стоит курсор в гриде (обращаешься к выделенной строке(или создаёшь "скрытый" едитбокс, который забинден на определённое поле и с него читаешь инфу и также делаешь запрос `update`))